draw big arrow between two points
I would like to draw a big arrow between two points. I found a helpful similar answer here. That answer is for chain join and it works fine. but I just copy it and apply it to draw command but no any effect:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, calc, chains}
\tikzset{
  myarr node/.style={
    shape=single arrow, draw=black, minimum width=20mm, anchor=tail,
    shape border uses incircle, single arrow head extend=+1pt,
    inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt},
  %
  myarr with anchors/.style 2 args={
    to path={
      let \p0=($(\tikztotarget.#2)-(\tikztostart.#1)$) in
      node[myarr node,
           minimum height={veclen(\x0,\y0)},
           shape border rotate={atan2(\y0,\x0)}] at (\tikztostart.#1) {}}
  },
  %
  myarr/.default={}{},
  myarr/.style 2 args={
    to path={
      \expanded{
        (\tikztostart#1) edge[path only, overlay, line to]
          coordinate[at start] (@start)
          coordinate[at end]   (@end) (\tikztotarget#2)}
      let \p0=($(@end)-(@start)$) in
      node[myarr node,
           minimum height={veclen(\x0,\y0)},
           shape border rotate={atan2(\y0,\x0)}] at (@start) {}}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[myarr] (0,0) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Output:


Like this:

Code:
\documentclass[border=.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=30pt,double,-latex] (-5,-3)--(3,2);
        \draw[red,line width=3pt,-stealth] (-2,4)--(3,2);
        \draw[cyan,line width=3pt,double,-latex] (4,6)--(3,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Is this what you need? the code is from the PGFmanual.


\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={single arrow, draw},
    rotate border/.style={shape border uses incircle, shape border rotate=#1}]
    \node {right};
    \node at (2,0) [shape border rotate=90]{up};
    \node at (1,1) [rotate border=37, inner sep=0pt]{$37^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}


right, this is the node behavior, that post intended to covert it to path and use it as a path style. it works on chain join lines but not work with draw command.
